# does cosmosdb update delete record even only single field change

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to understand how `cosmosdb udpate` works? In cosmosdb, there is a `upsert` operation to update or insert depending on whether the item exists in container or not. usually the flow is like this:

```
record = client.read_item(id, partition_key)
record['one_field'] = 'new_value'    
client.upsert(record)
```

My doubt here is whether such update operation will delete the original record even only a singe field is changed? If that is the case, then `update` becomes expensive is the record is large in size. Is my understanding correct here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosmos DB updates a document by replacing it, not by in-place update.

If you query (or read) a document, and then update some properties, you would then replace the document. Or, as you've done, call `upsert()` (which is similar to a replace, except that it will create a new document if the specified partition+id doesn't exist already).

The notion of "expensive" is not exactly easy to quantify; look at the returned headers to see the RU charge for a given upsert/replace, to determine the overall cost, and whether you'll need to scale your RU/sec setting based on overall usage patterns.